# Data Availability Chart in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, seaborn, bokeh

I am wondering if Python has something to plot the data availability of time series with multiple variables. An example is shown below taken from [Visavail.js - A Time Data Availability Chart](https://github.com/flrs/visavail#1-description).

[image]

Comment: I'm not aware, but in order to keep this on-topic please edit the question to give us the URL to a sample dataset with multiple timeseries variables containing implicit or explicit gaps. And post your own code attempt.

Comment: You could draw this exact chart with any of a half a dozen Python plotting and visualization libraries. However they are all general tools, and none of them, as far as I know, has anything pre-canned specifically for this exact narrow use-case. In any event asking for tool recommendations is explicitly off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion using plotly in a Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

**Code:**

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
from random import choices

# random data with a somewhat higher
# probability of 1 than 0 to mimic OPs data
random.seed(1)
vals=[0,1]
prob=[0.4, 0.6]
choices(vals, prob)

data=[]
for i in range(0,5):
    data.append([choices(vals, prob)[0] for c in range(0,10)])

# organize data in a pandas dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame(data).T
df.columns=['Balance Sheet', 'Closing Price', 'Weekly Report', 'Analyst Data', 'Annual Report']
drng=pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2080, 1, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), periods=df.shape[0]).tolist()
df['date']=[d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for d in drng]
dfm=pd.melt(df, id_vars=['date'], value_vars=df.columns[:-1])

# plotly express
fig = px.bar(dfm, x="date", y="variable", color='value', orientation='h',
             hover_data=["date"],
             height=600,
             color_continuous_scale=['firebrick', '#2ca02c'],
             title='Data Availabiltiy Plot',
             template='plotly_white',
            )

fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(title=''), xaxis=dict(title='', showgrid=False, gridcolor='grey',
                  tickvals=[],
                            )
                 )
fig.show()
```

Comment: thanks. you have helped me to learn the principle to solve this task.

Comment: @k.ko3n Glad to hear it! Please share if you find a perfect solution =)

Comment: @vestland Better late than never, but check out my Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try Plotly Gantt Charts

https://plotly.com/python/gantt/

The benefit of using this is, you can use actual time as value and also separate ressources and tasks.